# Looping through list and comparing to options in dropdown

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to loop through a list of ID's and submit each option with a value = id.
After submitting I am grabbing the resulting text I need from the last row of a table.
The basic functionality works, however, when I add more than one 'ID' to the list it only returns the result for last item in the list.

Here is my code:

```
#Go To Email Logs
driver.get("https://website.com/manager/email_logs.php")


#variables
SaleIds = ['47832', '47842', '49859', '50898']
dropdown = Select(driver.find_element_by_id('emailspecialid'))
options = dropdown.options


for option in options:
    value = option.get_attribute('value')
    for id in SaleIds:
        if id == value:
            option.click()
            driver.find_element_by_tag_name('input').submit()
            result = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/table[1]/tbody/tr[last()]/td[4]').text
            driver.implicitly_wait(100)
            print(result)
```

Comment: you shouldn't use `id` as a variable as it is a reserved word in python

Comment: check the size of options